How do I ensure route symmetry in IPv6 without NAT?
I am looking into IPv6, and my understanding is that the core goal of IPv6 is end-to-end routing. However, taking into consideration the requirements of the network I currently oversee, I am finding scenarios that I do not understand how to handle without NAT. I understand that NAT can be undesirable, but in these scenarios, I cannot think of a way to avoid asymmetric routing without employing NAT. My understanding is that NAT is not officially part of the IPv6 specification and there is some resistance to adopting a standard for it, though many equipment vendors do offer non-standard functionality for it. I would hope that if NAT functionality is not part of the standard for IPv6 that there would be alternative solutions to achieve the same functionality, but I am not finding much information on how to do that.
The first scenario I have involves connecting to a 3rd party's network via routers they send to us to deploy on our network. For disaster recovery purposes, we have routers deployed at two separate sites. We have several office locations where our users use the software that depends on these routers, and some office locations have favorable latency to site A, while other office locations have favorable latency to site B. This is a thick-client application, and our users can certainly tell that the application is slower when traffic isn't taking the optimal path. We like that we are able to send each office's traffic to the optimal router under normal operation, while still being able to send traffic to the other router if the optimal router is unavailable. In our current environment, we can SNAT our traffic before we send it to their router, so that they know to always send traffic responding to traffic from site A's SNAT address to site A's router, and always send traffic responding to traffic from site B's SNAT address to site B's router, thus preserving symmetry. In IPv6 without involving NAT, how would we achieve the same behavior? How will this 3rd party know which router our traffic came from without introducing a NAT themselves?
The second scenario is probably the same problem under the hood, but in a slightly different context. We have a different 3rd party who's thick-client software we use, but this traffic goes over the public internet. This application is especially latency sensitive, and our various ISPs have wildly different latencies for this traffic's destination. If I have a fairly expensive 50mbps internet connection that usually has very low latency to this application's servers, and a fairly inexpensive non-DIA 1 gig internet connection that usually has much higher latency to this application's servers (I strongly suspect this application is hosted from ISP A's colocation facility), I would like to be able to route internet traffic destined for this application's servers out connection A, while routing internet traffic to other services out connection B. In an end-to-end routed scenario, how would the return traffic know to take path A for the one particular application, but path B for everything else? This is a very easy problem to solve using NAT, but I am unaware of how to do this with no NAT involved.
Please forgive me if this is the wrong format of question for the Network Engineering stack exchange, or if this is a controversial topic. I have done some searching and haven't found much. I did find this blog post (https://blogs.infoblox.com/ipv6-coe/you-thought-there-was-no-nat-for-ipv6-but-nat-still-exists/) and they mention my use-case as a situation where NAT can be useful, but they don't elaborate on whether there are alternative ways to achieve the same thing in IPv6 with no NAT. I am mainly looking to understand whether the vendor-provided non-standard 'NAT66' functionality is basically inevitable for moving to IPv6 in a network like mine, or if there are other techniques or approaches that I am missing which achieve the same thing.

That is what BGP is for. BGP is the Internet routing protocol, and you run BGP with your upstream providers, and you can use its feature set to advertise your networks in the way you want. NAT is not a substitute for routing. One simple way to do it is to prepend prefix advertisements on the less preferred path, and the traffic will go to the more preferred path unless it is not available, then your provider's router will stop advertising that path. Remember that NAT66 is an experimental one-for-one NAT that prohibits the typical many-to-one IPv4-type NAT (NAPT).

The difficult bit comes when your preffered path difers by destination. Sometimes you can influence things by "communities" and similar but ultimately routing on the internet is controlled by the sender of the traffic.


if this is a controversial topic.

It's a controversial topic because there are a lot of people who would very much like NAT to die, but the reality is there are many scenarios where NAT is the least-bad solution.
Broadly, options for using multiple ISPs fall into three categories.
Use your own provider-independent address space and advertise it to the ISPs over BGP
This is a great option for large well-connected networks that have a few points of connection to the internet.
It's not so great at a small office level. "broadband" services will generally not let you advertise your own IP addresses and even if they did getting independent blocks of addresses for each office would not be seen as good network behaviour.
Also while it gives you a lot of control over the routing of your outbound traffic, you only have relatively limited control of the routing of inbound traffic.
If you are running a large network you can often solve a problem with a bad link by simply cutting out the middleman. If your network link's directly to Amazon's network then amazon will almost certainly send you packets directly without going through any intermediate networks but again for smaller networks this can often be difficult/expensive.
Assign multiple IP addresess to end systems
This was pushed heavily by the IPv6 proponents in the early days, but it suffers from the problem that the end system has no good way of knowing which source address it should use.
This could probablly be made to work in limited circumstances if all your end systems are tightly managed but it won't be easy.
Use NAT
While some vendors have implemented one to many NAT for IPv6, it is generally considered preferable to use one to one NAT. The IETF have published a standard for one to one NAT of IPv6 as an "experimental" RFC, while refusing to publish one for one to many NAT at all.
